# Using acronym in math mode

Tags: math-mode, acronyms

I am using the acronym package to set up my formula symbols. When I use them in normal math mode, everything is fine. But when I use one of them as a subscript, the font size is normal and not smaller like the other subscripts.

I tried with `\scriptsize`, but there is a warning that this is not supported, but it works. I also tried `\scriptstyle` but this has no effect.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acronym}
\begin{document}
    to big

    \begin{equation}
        \acs{v}_{\acs{N}}
    \end{equation}

    works, but with warning

    \begin{equation}
        \acs{v}_{\scriptsize\acs{N}}
    \end{equation}

    works not

    \begin{equation}
        \acs{v}_{\scriptstyle\acs{N}}
    \end{equation}

    \begin{acronym}
        \acro{v}[\ensuremath{v}]{Velocity}
        \acro{N}[\ensuremath{N}]{Count}
    \end{acronym}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think this is better done with `glossaries` rather than `acronym`.

Comment: I don't need the huge functionality of glossaries, so I wanted to use the lightweight one

Answer (score 3):

You can use macro `\text` from `amsmath` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \acs{v}_{\text{\acs{N}}}
\end{equation}
\begin{acronym}
\acro{v}[\ensuremath{v}]{Velocity}
\acro{N}[\ensuremath{N}]{Count}
\end{acronym}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is working. I think it is a bit misused, but why not.